# filter list sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

When I add this query to my SharePoint list:

```
    <Query>
<Where>
<Or>
<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
<FieldRef Name="UgroupA"/></Membership>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name="UgroupA"/>
<Value Type="Integer">
<UserID Type="Integer"/>
</Value>
</Eq>
</Or>
</Where>
</Query>
```

It shows this error :
[image]

this is the transtalation of the message :

the server can not execute the query, soap: ServerUne exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException.one or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these champs.0x81020014

Any ideas.

Comment: Please, provide exception message in english or text version for translation.

Comment: I will  try to translate the message

Comment: this is the message : the server can not execute the query,  soap: ServerUne exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException.one or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these champs.0x81020014

Comment: translate the details as well pls

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing   `Type="Integer"` from `<UserID />` tag.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
    <Or>
    <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
    <FieldRef Name="UgroupA"/></Membership>
    <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="UgroupA"/>
    <Value Type="Integer">
    <UserID />
    </Value>
    </Eq>
    </Or>
    </Where>
    </Query>
```

See the below link for same example in MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx

Comment: I steel have the same problem, and the query works just fine in another list.

Comment: check if fieldref name 'UgroupA' is the correct name and is user or a group field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CAML Query. The  Type="Integer" in "UserID" are not needed here.

```
<Query>    
<Where>
<Or>
<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
<FieldRef Name="UgroupA"/></Membership>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name="UgroupA"/>
<Value Type="Integer">
<UserID />
</Value>
</Eq>
</Or>
</Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: The "Or" is required , only the Type="Integer" in "UserID" is not required

Answer (score -2):

i am giving you CAML query example. Modify according your need. Thanks

```
<View><Query><Where><And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='ProjectId' /></IsNotNull><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='RoleId' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" YourValue "</Value></Neq><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='RoleId' /><Value Type='Lookup'> YourValue </Value></Neq><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='RoleId' /><Value Type='Lookup'> YourValue </Value></Neq><Eq><FieldRef Name='IsActive' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></And></And></And></And></Where></Query></View>
```